# Merge of Access Databases

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, merge

I'm trying to write a program in **VB.net** which is a 'fancy' database front end.
What the program is meant to do is store the database locally on the users machine from a shared location where the 'server' database is sat.

Both the Local and Server copy are stored into a dataset, and the program then checks the server copy to see if its had any updates recently. If it does, it only then downloads the updates to reduce bandwidth.

What I am trying to do is force the local database to take on the server databases changes. However, when using data-adapter.update it fails to notice any changes as at the moment the way it reloads the server dataset is to clear it, and reload it from scratch.

Is there any efficient ways of forcing the server dataset onto the local one, and then forcing the local dataset to re-write the database in a BGW? As I said before, the data-adapter.update doesn't seem to save the changes if I just clear the local one and copy the server one to the local one.

Apologies if I'm completely going the wrong way for this. Any advice, or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

John

```
    dsLocalDB.Clear() 'Clear the local dataset
    dsLocalDB = dbServerDB.Copy 'copy the server dataset to the local dataset
    LoadData() 'let the application reload all the new records


    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daLocalDB) 'Create a COmmand Builder
    For i = 1 To TableNames.GetUpperBound(0) 'Loop through all the tables which have been stored as an array
        For Each row As DataRow In dsLocalDB.Tables(TableNames(i)).Rows 'Loop through the rows, so we can see if it detects modified data. For testing purposes.
            If row.RowState = DataRowState.Modified Then 'Its found modified data!
                MsgBox("Found Modified Data Row!") 'Output a message
                Exit For 'exit the for loop
            End If
        Next
        daLocalDB.Update(dsLocalDB, TableNames(i)) 'Update the local database
    Next i
```

Comment: Have you added time-stamps for creation and update to all your tables?

Comment: I haven't, however I plan to do this on each record. However, this only needs to sync onto one side. The local copy will never be written too, it will always be read only. Users will only ever read the data from it and it will just be a 'copy' of the latest Server one which that machine managed to grab.

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand? To me, the easiest thing is to store a last updated date and just copy down anything above that.

Comment: When I try to write back to the local database using the updated dataset. It doesn't store the data back into the database as its not picking up changes. So for some reason, the data-adapter isn't written back to the local database. What I need to do is compare the local database to the server one, and any changes on the server one. It will then download those changes to the local one.

Comment: If your code is not working, perhaps you should post some code?

Comment: Uploaded the bit what i've tried, and doesn't work. It doesn't report any errors etc, just doesn't update the local database.

Comment: I am beginning to wonder why you don't simply zip and copy the whole db across, after all, MS Access is file based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18027/Take-Data-Offline-Using-Microsoft-Synchronization

PS:
If you're open to well-meant advice: You're doing it wrong. Don't ever keep two databases. 
Syncing two database is a very delicate procedure. 
Even cluster applications use live-syncing.
If you don't have a few years of experience, you will produce a chaos in no time at all.
Read the disclaimer in the article (NO WARRANTIES, EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY).

Comment: Sorry, it probably was the way I wrote it. I have no intention in keeping them synced as such. All I need it to do is to make sure it downloads all changes from the server copy when it can. And due to it doing it already in a dataset, would it be easier to upload that dataset to the database instead of hogging more bandwidth?